# IE8 won`t submit on enter when you have multiple forms

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-8

if you have 3 forms (shown below) and you set two of forms to not to display (display:none;) and you use javascript to toggle through each form, the forms that were set to hidden, when you set them to visible and you try to submit a form by pressing enter, it won`t submit.

the only form that will submit if the first form that is visible by default.

this works in ie7 and ie6, but not ie8 (go figure)

i am using jquery to hide and show my forms, but this should not be an issue. 
i have as well tried using different css rules (like visibility:hidden) and still the same problem;

```
<a href="" onclick="$('#form1').show();$('#form2').hide();$('#form3').hide();">form1</a>
  <a href="" onclick="$('#form1').hide();$('#form2').show();$('#form3').hide();">form2</a>
  <a href="" onclick="$('#form1').hide();$('#form2').show();$('#form3').hide();">form3</a> 

<div id="form1">
      <form method="get"  action="test1/" >
        <input type="text" name="text1" id="text1" />
        <input type="text" name="text2" id="text2" />
        <input type="text" name="text3" id="text3" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit1"  value="submit1"/>
      </form>
  </div>

<div id="form2" >
<form method="get" action="test2/" style="display:none" >
<input type="text" name="text4" id="text4" />
<input type="text" name="text5" id="text5" />
<input type="text" name="text6" id="text6" />
<input type="submit" name="submit2"  value="submit2"/>
</form>
</div>

<div id="form3" >
  <form method="get" action="test3/" style="display:none" >
      <input type="text" name="text7" id="text7" />
      <input type="text" name="text8" id="text8" />
      <input type="text" name="text9" id="text9" />
      <input type="submit" name="submit3"  value="submit3"/>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I assume you've made sure that one of the form inputs has focus when pressing enter?

Comment: Just wondering, why do your forms contain three textfields with identical names and id's, that won't work, you're looking for classes (I think).

Comment: Identical names is fine (unless you are using PHP and want to use $_POST/GET/REQUEST). Identical ids is forbidden in HTML (and XHTML) though.

Comment: i have changed all the textbox ids to unique ids and i still get the same results.

and yes when i press enter i do make sure the one of the textboxes are in focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m afraid I don’t have IE 8 here to test on, but you might try different CSS properties as a workaround:

```
<style type="text/css">
.hide {
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
}
</style>

<a href="" onclick="$('#form1').removeClass('hide');$('#form2').addClass('hide');$('#form3').removeClass('hide');">form1</a>
<a href="" onclick="$('#form1').addClass('hide');$('#form2').removeClass('hide');$('#form3').addClass('hide');">form2</a>
<a href="" onclick="$('#form1').addClass('hide');$('#form2').removeClass('hide');$('#form3').addClass('hide');">form3</a>
```

This would have the same visual effect as `display: none;`.

Answer (score 0):

I see you're using jQuery - you could probably do something along the lines of

```
$(function() {  // execute when document ready
  $("input").keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode==13) { // enter 
      var form = $(this).parents("form").get(0); // first <form> tag that is a parent.
      if (form) form.submit();
      return e.preventDefault(); // stop it from activating in other browsers.
    }
  });
});
```

That should ensure when you hit enter that a form submits.

Comment: the only reason why this solution wouldn't if you had an auto complete drop down. when you hit enter to select an item from the drop down..it would just submit the form.

you wouldn't want that in some cases